# capistrano run_locally wrong number of arguments

Tags: capistrano3

```
after :finishing, :send_rollbar_notice do
  on roles(:web) do
    access_token = 'special_key_goes_here'
    environment = fetch(:environment)
    local_username = `whoami`.strip
    revision = `git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H"`
    curl_command = %{curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/deploy/ -F 'access_token=#{access_token}' -F 'environment=#{environment}' -F 'revision=#{revision}' -F 'local_username=#{local_username}'}
    puts curl_command
    output = run_locally "#{curl_command}"
    puts output
  end
end
```

Can someone help me figure out why I'm getting the follow error after I run the `cap deploy` command?

`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: FYI - when I use `execute` it seems to work, but on the remote server. I'd like to run this command locally.

Comment: what is the difference bwteen `execute` and `run`

Answer (score 1):

Got it! :)

Replace `on roles(:web) do` with `run_locally do`